# Rails dynamic session timeout using devise and session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, devise, session-timeout, session-store

I know i can do dynamic session timeout (per user) with devise like described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically)

This worked fine before but now i'm using rails session store and it doesn't work anymore.

I googled quite a long time but didn't find an answer, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it now with some before_filters:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :update_session, :check_if_session_is_valid

  ...
  def check_if_session_is_valid
    session_timeout = current_user.try(:session_timeout) || 1800
    if session[:timestamp] <= session_timeout.seconds.ago.to_i
      session[:user_id] = nil
    end
  end

  def update_session
    session[:timestamp] = Time.now.to_i
  end
```

And in the controller which is used by the poller i added this (the session shouldn't get updated by the poller):

```
skip_before_filter :update_session, :only => :get_new
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest approach for session timeout using devise would be to use Devise 'timeoutable' module. Following 2 lines will serve the session timeout functionality, Only if u are using devise in your Rails application.

Step 1: **In your User.rb Model** declare this

```
 devise: timeoutable
```

Step 2:

in  **app/config/initializers/devise.rb**  add following line, default set by Devise is 30 minutes.

```
config.timeout_in = 15.minutes
```

Hope this works for you!

Thanks!